# how to construct target url for client API in JAX-RS effectively?

Tags: java, jax-rs

I see there are  two ways to construct a target URI using Client API in JAX-RS

**First** (borrowed from [here](http://htmlpreview.github.io/?https://github.com/javaee-samples/javaee7-hol/blob/master/docs/javaee7-hol.html#jaxrs)):

```
Client client;
WebTarget target;

@Inject HttpServletRequest httpServletRequest;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    target = client
                .target("http://" +
                httpServletRequest.getLocalName() +
                ":" +
                httpServletRequest.getLocalPort() +
                "/" +
                httpServletRequest.getContextPath() +
                "/webresources/movie/");

}
```

**second**

```
Client client;
WebTarget target;

@Context UriInfo uriInfo;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    client = ClientBuilder.newClient();
    String uri = uriInfo.getAbsolutePath().toString();
    target = client
                .target(uri + "/webresources/movie/");

}
```

The first uses `HttpServletRequest` and the second uses `UriInfo` for injection. Is using one over the other beneficial in any situations. if so when?

Comment: I doubt `UriInfo` is available for injection during a `PostConstruct`.  More importantly - why are you trying to invoke your own API from within the code?